# If object of a nested array in mongodb doesn't have a field, then display default value

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

### 1.) What I have done

I am trying to query over data in MongoDB which looks like this:

```
"AllData": [
  {
    "name": "Company 1",
    "data": [
      {
        "Brand": "Brand 1", // Brand field present
        "Product Name": "Product 1",
      },
      {
        "Brand": "Brand 1", // Brand field present
        "Product Name": "Product 2",
      },
      {
        "Brand": "Brand 2", // Brand field present
        "Product Name": "Product 1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Company 2",
    "data": [
      {
        "Product Name": "Product 1", // Brand field not present
      },
      {
        "Product Name": "Product 2", // Brand field not present
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see for `Company 1`, the `Brand` field is available whereas for `Company 2` it is not.
The *query* I'm using to get data is:

```
result = await colc.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$AllData" },
  { $unwind: "$AllData.data" },
  { $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "AllData.data.Product Name": { $regex: product, $options: "i"}
        },
        { "AllData.active": true }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "AllData.data": 1,
      //  "AllData.data.Brand": { $ifNull: [ "$AllData.data.Brand", "$AllData.name" ] }
    }
  }
])
```

The query returns every object from the nested array that matches with the `product` as an individual document.

**This works perfectly!**

### 2) What I am trying to achieve

For `Company 1` I have an `AllData.data.Brand` field and for `Company 2` I don't.
If the object has a `Brand` field missing, then instead of that, the *Company Name* i.e. `AllData.name` field should be returned.

Something like this:

```
"AllData": [
 {
    "name": "Company 2",
    "data": [
      {
        "Brand": "Company 2", // Brand field replaced with Company 2
        "Product Name": "Product 1",        
      }
    ]
 }]
```

If I uncomment this line:

```
"AllData.data.Brand": { $ifNull: [ "$AllData.data.Brand", "$AllData.name" ] }
```

I'm getting an error `MongoError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Path collision at AllData.data.Brand remaining portion data.Brand at MessageStream.messageHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path collision problem arises because in the same $ project stage you have entered the "AllData.data" field twice :

```
"AllData.data": 1,
"AllData.data.Brand": { $ifNull: [ "$AllData.data.Brand", "$AllData.name" ] }
```

Try using an addFields stage instead of your commented line:

```
$addFields: {
  "AllData.data.Brand": { $ifNull: [ "$AllData.data.Brand", "$AllData.name" ] }
}
```